# Same Flutter codebase but Firebase login works for web app but fails for iOS app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter app compiled for both web and iOS. For several months now we having been using the development and staging projects in Firebase. Now that we are ready to deploy we just recently created the production Firebase project.

However after deploying the app the iPad version fails to authenticate. However if I go to the web version and use the exact same credentials it authenticates just fine. What would cause this? The error code that Firebase returns is simply 'wrong-password'.

Have had other team members try and it fails for them also so I know its not me just mis-spelling the password.

BTW, after creating the production project the app would fail to launch and Firebase was throwing an error saying "A database named Default already exists". One stack overflow post recommended to pass the name parameter to the `Firebase.initializeApp` call and that did fix that exception from being thrown.

BEFORE - worked fine for staging and development

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

AFTER - had to add name property to resolve 'a database named default already exists' error

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  name: 'default',
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

However once I got past that then the authentication simply started failing. I'm wondering if something changed with Firebase projects since August of last year (when the dev and staging projects were created) and so the newly created production project is different somehow?

Appreciate any insight any one can offer!

Comment: Are you using the lastest versions of the packages? Its always the packages being too old with such issues. Let me know if this fixes your issue btw

Comment: To make sure, did you register your ios app to the firebase production and replace the GoogleService-info.plist?
Did you use flutterfire configure to setup your firebase?

Comment: @FaBotch yes ran flutter fire configure to setup everything

Comment: @FreakyAli You may be on to something with the package versions. My co-worker mentioned how back in November the build was failing in CodeMagic due to a specific Firebase package and to fix it he removed the caret on the version number so that the package was pinned to that specific version. The issue has been closed on CodeMagic's GitHub so I think the bug has been fixed so will try upgrading the packages today and see how that goes. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Be sure to let me know i would love to add an answer about this

Comment: @FreakyAli turns out that somehow the FlutterFire config command did not update the GoogleService-info.json file. Not sure how it got skipped but luckily my coworker caught it. Worked great after that.

Comment: @FaBotch you called it, the Google service-info.plist was not updated. I thought the FlutterFire config command updates that file? Make an answer and I’ll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment section, `GoogleService-info.plist` was not updated.

I have tested and `flutterfire configure` only update `lib/firebase_options.dart` `/ios/firebase_app_id_file.json` and `google-services.json` and for some reason ignore the plist file